# Unity + Moonsharp : iOS release version > Not work

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, lua, moonsharp

We are using Moonsharp (Lua Interpreter) con our Unity new Game (Unity v.5.4.1)

On Android works well. And... thats de key...

However in iOS in the DEV version there are no problems, **but in the RELEASE version it does not run correctly.**

We have the following error:

```
"ScriptRunTimeException: Can not convert clr type System.MonoType"
```

What kind of differences between ios develop or release version?

I repeat. We only get that error once it is released to the iTunes Store, not in Dev mode.

Any solution?

Comment: Check if you have `UserData.RegisterAssembly()` in your code.

Comment: yes! of course.
We use this.

Comment: Did you try the answer I left?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug.

Change `UserData.RegisterAssembly()`

to

`UserData.RegisterAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly);` or something similar.
Just use the `RegisterAssembly` overload function with the `Assembly` parameter. This will likely fix your problem.